# Why Js function returning [59, f]

Tags: javascript

```js
let p2 = function(arr, index,value)
{
    let array1 = [5,3,6,1,8,5,8,32];
    array1 = arr;
    return [
        array1[index] = value,
        function count()
        {
            for(let i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(array1[i]);
            }
        }
    ]
};
console.log(p2(arr, 3,59));
```

In this code I'm trying the print the array after replacing the value but I;m getting [59,f]. Idk what f is here.

Comment: system is not able to check what is arr here? `console.log(p2(arr, 3,59));`

Answer (score 0):

You have the following return :

```
return [
        array1[index] = value,
        function count()
        {
            for(let i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(array1[i]);
            }
        }
    ]
```

So the JS engine returns an array, where `59` is from the statement `array1[index] = value` and the `f` is the function that is at the 1st index of the returned array, which is :

```
function count()
        {
            for(let i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(array1[i]);
            }
        }
```

Not sure what your intention which function `count` is, but you would probably want to move the `return` statement at last to get some meaningful value.

**[Update]:**

You cannot return 2 values from a non-generator function, so it's better to return an object that has your desired result, and use it after the function call completes :

```js
let arr = [5,3,6,1,8,5,8,32];

let p2 = function(arr, index,value)
{
    let array1 = [...arr];
    array1[index] = value;
    return {value: array1[index], res: arr} 
};

const { value, res } = p2(arr, 3, 59);
console.log(value, res);
```

Comment: I want to return the element of the array instead of the function itself.

Comment: @HimanshuPal What is the expected output?

Comment: output :- 59, [5,3,6,1,8,5,8,32]